# Can two users share the same browser and site but have different sessions

Tags: php, session

Although it probably doesn't happen often, it could happen that UserA is logged in and has an active session. Then UserB picks up the laptop and wants to use the same site. In PHP is it possible to test for this and allow this or is it one user per session.

The example I ran into is while testing I had userA logged in to their profile, then for userB I clicked a link to reset their password, but instead of hitting the password reset page I was redirected to the profile page for userA. This is the way I coded it, but I wondering if these days with family using on laptop for everyone should I devise a way to give each person their own session for cases like the email link?

**Edit:** I've decided to abandon this idea altogether. I'll leave it up to the user to secure their session.

Comment: How is your server going to know who is physically using the laptop? It's not really possible by conventional (sensible) means.

Comment: lolll very funny and true! @Leigh

Comment: Very true. So its up to the user to secure their session.

Comment: @John Indeed, they need to log out, or close the browser (clearing session cookies)

Comment: Create a time stamp with session, telling the server if user has not made any clicks in the site, to expire the session. That is the only hope you have in your problem

Comment: @Leigh I deleted my answer, but I don't understand why you didn't think it was worthy of an answer (and in a very disrespectful way) -- the answer is really that this can't be done.  There needs to be a *trigger* for the website to know that the physical user has switched; handing the laptop to someone else is not enough

Comment: @ExplosionPills The answer is: this can be done in very roundabout ways that require extra work from the user, or kludgy workarounds. Your contribution was tantamount to "No"; which wasn't helpful, informative or entirely accurate. I expect that people over a certain degree of reputation to put effort into their answers, instead of just spamming one liners for "quick wins"

Comment: @Leigh just because an answer is short or long does not necessarily mean it's inferior or superior.  The "No" answer is useful since it stops wasting time looking for a solution that's not there -- it's not really "no," it's just that there is nothing *you* (as a developer) can do about this.  It requires the user to take some action other than what was requested in the question (i.e. handing off the laptop).  I'm sorry you think that my answers are spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just posting this to show how it could be possible, but I **STRONGLY** suggest you never ever even try to use this technique. It opens up entire worlds of security problems, and any minor convenience you could offer your users will be absolutely annihilated by the problems it causes.

That being said, you can use PHP's `trans_sid` ("transparent session ID") support, where the session ID is automatically embedded into URLs and as hidden form fields. This would allow you to open multiple windows, each with its own session, with no sharing betweeen the windows.

Basically you'd turn off cookie-based sessions and use ONLY the transparent IDs: PHP will automatically modify `<a href="...">` to add in the session ID parameter into query strings, and insert hidden form fields as needed. It will not work on JS code and the like, but you can add in the ID yourself there.

However, here's the problem: Now that session ID is embedded in the URLs and forms, bookmarking a page on your site will tie that bookmark to the particular session in use at the time. Cut 'n pasting a url to share something will also transmit the user's session to whoever they send the link to. Clicking on any links to the outside world from your site will transmit the session ID as part of the referer. e.g. you've just made session hijacking utterly trivial, because the user will be yelling their session ID from the rooftops everytime they do anything.

---

simpler solution: Use the browser's "porn mode" so each window has its own cookie storage, separating each user's window/session from the others.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with chrome and firefox so far I am concerned (I use no other browser). 
This fonctionality is called "multisession".

In chrome it can be activated by going into chrome://chrome/settings/ and adding a user to chrome.

About the com :

> How is your server going to know who is physically using the laptop? It's not really possible by conventional (sensible) mean

the server just ask you an id to get your session. Technicaly, this id is stored into a cookie so, it is linked to the physical machine